# SELECT INTO with EXECUTE() in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server-2008

This works:

```
drop table #A

select v = getdate() 
into #A

select * from #A
```

But not this (no result):

```
drop table #A

create table #A (v varchar(30))

declare @x varchar(30) = 'select v = getdate() into #A'
execute(@x)

select * from #A
```

I need to be able to do this above one to address a scenario. Must be simple and silly, but just trying to understand why this just doesn't work like first one?
Please advise. Thanks experts!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can propose workaround and move all you script to @x variable.

So your script will be as:

```
declare @x nvarchar(MAX) = '
    drop table IF EXISTS #A
    select v=getdate() into #A
    select * from #A'

PRINT(@x)
EXEC(@x)
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. point is not just to SELECT after SELECT INTO, that is only just for verification. I need more processing after that I cannot put whole stuff into the variable. What I am trying to understand is what is different with the temp table within a variable via execute() and why it is not behaving exactly as temp table declared outside. If both temp tables are different, how to select...into this table? I know we can use insert with select but that's a performance issue so don't want that option.

Comment: I could use the same technique to insert again into another table and capture results from there. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

MSDN says

> SELECT…INTO creates a new table in the default filegroup and inserts the resulting rows from the query into it.

So if you create table prior to `select into`, you cannot use `select into,` you need to use `insert into`

Comment: Thanks. Insert into comes with a huge performance cost and that option is not a go for us as we have bad experience with huge resultsets. So we are trying to execute dynamic query with select into temp table and capture results from there, so need an alternative.